# ListBox Binding in windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to bind the item source in the List that resides in Pivot Control.How can i bind the itemsouce either in xaml or code.This is my code

```
<controls:Pivot x:Name="Category_pivot"  Foreground="Black" FontSize="22">
                <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="45"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

            <ListBox x:Name="d" ItemsSource="{Binding Item}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                      
                        <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"   ></Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

            </DataTemplate>
                </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot>
       </Grid>
```

Comment: What's the data you're trying to bind (your classes)?

Comment: Have you set the `DataContext` for your page?

Comment: I am trying to bind the class Item to the ListBox.

Comment: @StepTNT I am beginer to windows phone so i don't know how to do it.

Comment: In your page's constructor or any other appropriate event, call `DataContext = your-view-model`. Where does that `Item` come from?

Comment: I think that you should follow this tutorials series because it can really help you in understanding how to work with MVVM on WP. http://wp.qmatteoq.com/first-steps-with-caliburn-micro-in-windows-phone-8-the-theory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have spent too much time on this, but it bothered me...

You used Foreground="Black" in your example, and this means that the header is black so in a OOB project it is black-on-black.

Here is my XAML:

```
    <phone:Pivot x:Name="Category_pivot" FontSize="22">
            <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="45"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox x:Name="d" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageSource}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot>
```

And my C#:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public class Data
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<SubData> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubData
    {
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
    }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<Data> list = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        Data d = new Data() { Title = "my page 1" };
        d.Items = new ObservableCollection<SubData>();
        d.Items.Add(new SubData() { ImageSource = "1" });
        d.Items.Add(new SubData() { ImageSource = "2" });
        list.Add(d);

        d = new Data() { Title = "my page 2" };
        d.Items = new ObservableCollection<SubData>();
        d.Items.Add(new SubData() { ImageSource = "A" });
        d.Items.Add(new SubData() { ImageSource = "B" });
        list.Add(d);

        Category_pivot.ItemsSource = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you vary much.I got my answer.